# How to use images sliced with the slicing tool of the XCode5 assets catalog

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5

In the assets catalog in the new XCode5 there's a tool to slice your images, I assume this is used for images that are going to be stretched, and it has the same effect as using the `resizableImageWithCapInsets`: method on a `UIImage` object.

My question is, once I sliced my image, how do I use it in my code? I just create the image with the size I want and it's stretched automatically using the insents I set in the slicing tool? Or I have to create it using a special way?

I haven't found any documentation about it yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The image slicing in Xcode 5 works with `[UIImage imageNamed:@"blah"];`. You don't have to do anything in the code. The slicing information is automagically contained in the `UIImage` that gets returned.

You can set everything using the asset catalog: retina, iPad, slicing, etc...

Then give the whole set of images a name and just use that name.

Your app will then pull out the correct image from the catalog including all the slicing information.

Comment: So, I dont have to do anything, it will be stretched automatically using the insents I set?

Comment: If you have set them in the asset catalog then yes.

Comment: Ok, that's the confirmation I needed.